# C# : How can I make dynamically controls for a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, winforms

When I write a number in a label and press a button, it must show me a dynamical allocation: the first column is number current, then 4 columns with comboboxes. So, when I press 3 it might show 3 rows with number and comboboxes and so on.  How can I make this allocation? with multidimensional array and list of objects

Comment: Can you please specify which framework you use? Windows Forms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: i am using windows forms

Comment: What did you tried. We're not code providers..

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Then edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want to add controls to your form in run-time and based on an input?

Comment: Yesss @roozbehS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your `Form` and then add rows to it as below:

```
private void AddRow()
{
    //First create and setup your controls that are supposed to be in a row:
    ComboBox cb1 = new ComboBox(){ /* settings */ };
    // Other Controls


    //Then add them to the FlowLayoutPanel:
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cb1);
    // add other controls

    // Then set a line break at the end of row:
    flowLayoutPanel1.SetFlowBreak(cb4, true); // let's say cb4 is the last control of the row.

}
```

Then you can use the method like this:

```
int numRows;
bool success = int.TryParse(textBox1.text, out numRows); // lets say textBox1 contains number of rows.
if(success)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        AddRow();
    }
}
```